# tmux: allow-rename, but ALSO override?

Tags: tmux

I'd like to be able to issue a command like this:

```
tmux new-window -n irc ssh -t eco /usr/bin/weechat
```

and have the title of the new window be "irc". Instead, as soon as weechat launches, the title changes to weechat.

I had been under the impression based on the tmux man page that if you set a window title explicitly, automatic-rename would be disabled for you:

> **automatic-rename**
>
> [...] This flag is automatically disabled for an individual window when a
>   name is specified at creation with new-window or new-session, or later
>   with rename-window, or with a terminal escape sequence.

But that seems to not be the case. What am I missing here? I *do* want automatic-rename in most cases - I just want to **also** be able to specify `-n windowname` and have it take precedence.